# Java Kotlin Generic passing a class getter as parameter in function

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics, android-diffutils

I m doing something about the android DiffUtil and i want to make it generic.I want to pass the getter function (itemGetter) when creating the class A  but when i declare the type of itemGetter in the constructor. I don't know how to declare it. ()->V  is incorrect. because
I can't doing something like item.itemGetter()
The Class T is about a class with a itemGetter

```kotlin
class T() {
    val item = ....
    
    fun itemGetter(): String {
        return this.item
    }
}


class A<T,V>(var item1 :T , var item2:T ,var itemGetter: ()->V){
    fun comparing(item1: T,item2:T): Boolean {
        return item1.itemGetter()===item2.itemGetter()
    }
}
```

### Thanks

update specific Example

```
class DiffCallBackUtil<T>(var oldList: ArrayList<T>, var newList: ArrayList<T> ) : DiffUtil.Callback() {


   override fun areItemsTheSame(oldi: Int, newi: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldi] === newList[newi]

    }
}
```

Because we check the are itemsTheSame require to compare the name or id or
something instance in the model T, Therefore, i need pass a getter as function in the Model T  to the DiffCallBackUtil.
Therefore, i can invoke `oldList[oldi].getName()===newList[newi].getName()`

Comment: What do you wanted to do exactly?

Comment: i want to know how to declare itemGetter: ()->V , because ()->V  is false. i want to make it that item1.itemGetter() is available

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, I still couldn't understand... What is the use of itemGetter? And if you declared it in the class why do you want it as a lambda?

Comment: Your question is especially confusing because your classes have one-letter names just like the conventional names of generic types. It’s really hard to see what you’re trying to do. Also your function parameters are shadowing the class properties.

Comment: i have update the question. . Thanks

Comment: I think you need type `T.()->V` Also, in Kotlin a getter function is redundant unless it requires a parameter. The property already has a getter that you can customize if you want to do something other than returning the backing field.